# How can I add section header in horizontal

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

How do I add an horizontal Section Header in my `UICollectionView`, once the scrolling is horizontally? I'm trying but it automatically goes as vertical header when I mark the box **"Section Header"** in Storyboard. How can I do that?

[image: Scroll Image]

Edit:

That’s how the app should looks like. The header I’m trying to implement should appear above the UICollectionView where it’s written “Categoria”

[image: Final App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I add an horizontal Section Header in my UICollectionView, once the scrolling is horizontally?

You can't. The whole idea is meaningless. Horizontal scrolling flow layouts have vertical section headers, and vertical scrolling flow layouts have horizontal section headers.

If you want some other behavior, you'll have to write your own layout.

**EDIT** It turns out that all you wanted is a static label, not part of the collection view at all.

Comment: Hello Matt! So, would you recommend me any tutorial? I need to add headers on my horizontal scroll

Comment: As I said, the idea is meaningless. I can't even envision what a horizontal header for a horizontally scrolling layout would even look like.

Comment: Matt, I just edited the post. I added a picture to clarify how the app should looks like. You’ll be able to see where the header should be implemented.

Comment: Oh, I thought was my answer. Hold on

Comment: Check once again, please @matt

Comment: Why is that a header? Does the word Categorias, in your plan, scroll sideways when the user scrolls the collection view??

Comment: It shouldn’t be a header? No, it’s static just to say to the user that the options below are all categories

Comment: So it’s not a header. It’s not even part of the collection view. It’s just a label above the collection view.

Comment: Did you see like a shadow effect above Categories? I thought it was a header.

Comment: That’s irrelevant. How to make the shadow has nothing to do with what Categorias is.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt! I appreciate your attention